# Array of stagewebviews

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I am in the need of multiple staged WebViews for holding multiple loaded websites at the same time.

I was hoping to manage this by making an array of webviews object, so i could call them later as view[i].

```
var view:Array=[webview0, webview1, webview2];
for each (var v in view){
var v:StageWebView = new StageWebView();
```

This gives error: 1086: Syntax error: expecting semicolon before left bracket.

Does someone know how to make an array like that?

Answer (score 1):

You're doing something really weird there in terms of syntax. If you just want an **Array** of freshly created instances, it goes like that:

```
// Initialize the array.
var Views:Array = new Array;

// This loop counts 0,1,2.
for (var i:int = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    // Create a new instance.
    // Yes, you can omit () with new operator if there are no arguments.
    var aView:StageWebView = new StageWebView;

    // Assign the new element to your array.
    Views[i] = aView;
}
```

Or, if you need only 3 then you don't need to go algorithmic.

```
var Views:Array = [new StageWebView, new StageWebView, new StageWebView];
```

Answer (score 0):

Not on topic but related: 
Here is an example of one HTML page hold multiple StageWebViews 
https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/tryit.asp?filename=trymap_basic_many

Comment: Please do not post link-only answers but provide some explanation and a code example to make your answer useful even if the link you show at some point does no longer work.